# How we can build CFG for a context-free language

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, pushdown-automaton, context-free-language

Build CFG for the following language: {a^i b^j c^k |  j not equal to i + k}. I have already tried the following CFG, but it miss some cases.

```
S---> AB
A---> ab|aAb|aA|NULL
B---> bc|bBc|cB|NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current CFG will produce some strings that are not in the language. For example, the string ab is the string with i = 1, j = 1, k = 0 so i+j = k. This string is produced by your grammar.

One way to approach this would be to split the language into the union of two languages: {a^i b^j c^k | i+k < j} U {a^i b^j c^k | i+k > j}. We can then build a CFG for each language. Let S be the start state, L be the grammar rule for i+k < j, G be the grammar rule for i+k > j.

It was helpful to me to think about this cancelling out each 'b' with an 'a' or a 'c' in the string. Once you've canceled out as much as possible there should either be some leftover b's (i+j < k) or some leftover a's and/or c's (i+j > k).

S ---> L | G 
L ---> HBF 
B ---> b | bB 
G ---> aG | Gc | aHF | HFc 
H ---> aHb | NULL 
F ---> bHc | NULL

H produces all strings where there are a balanced number of a's and b's and F produces all strings where there are a balanced number of b's and c's. So think of L as balanced number of a's and b's followed by 1 or more extra b's followed by balanced number of b's and C's.

Similarly for G, you can produce 1 or more extra a's at the beginning and/or 1 or more extra c's at the end. In the middle you have balanced numbers of a's and b's (cancelling each other out) and balanced numbers of b's and c's (cancelling each other out).